# Python Conditional NaN Value Replacement of existing Values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to transform my DataFrame witch i loaded from a CSV.
In that CSV are columns that have NaN / no Values. The goal is to replace them all!

For Example in column 'gh' row 45 (as shown in the picture: [Input Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF2XN.png)) is a value missing. I like to replace it with the value of row 1, because 'latitude','longitude', 'time' ,'step','valid_time' are equal. So I like to have a Condition based replacement by those values. But not just for 'gh' but also for meanSea, msl, t, u and v.

[Input Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF2XN.png)

I tryed something like that (just for 'gh'):

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    value = row["gh"]
    if pd.isnull(value):
        for j,rowx in df.iterrows():
            if row["latitude"]==rowx["latitude"] and row["longitude"]==rowx["longitude"] and row["time"]==rowx["time"] and row["step"]==rowx["step"]and row["valid_time"]==rowx["valid_time"]:
                valuex = rowx["gh"] 
                row["gh"]=valuex
                break;
```

[My Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnDYP.png)

This is very inefficent for big Data Frames so I need a better solution.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all values can be found somewhere in the dataset, the easiest way is to sort your df by those columns ('latitude','longitude', 'time' ,'step','valid_time') and forward fill your NaN's:

`df.sort_values(by=['latitude','longitude', 'time' ,'step','valid_time']).ffill()`

However, **this fails** if there are rows which do not have a counterpart somewhere else in the dataset.